# How Much Ram Does Ubuntu Need To Run

Tags: mac, ram

Well i have an old eMac and i wanted to replace the operating system with Ubuntu but I don"t want to break it.

Comment: You may receive a better support if you include more details on what you wish to do with your Ubuntu installed on that eMac. Ubuntu will run with very low resources but it may not reach your expectations thus you won't feel pleased with Ubuntu. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't require much to run, [(500 MB)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) but it will be slow. you will need around (1-2 GB to have a smoother system), but this is up to every user what they can handle.

I would try [lubuntu](http://www.lubuntu.net/) or [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) on an old Emac.

Try with the live-CD first so you know ruffly how fast the system will be. The CD will be slower than a hard drive but it will give a hint on which system will be fastest.

For more info check this question:

- [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right
  for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/q/206407/10698)

Answer (score 1):

It depends also on what distribution you want to use or what you should use

Basically, older distros are fine for older pc's and newer ones for newer pc's.
Example... why don't you try Karmic Koala?